# Nested Iteratees

Tags: haskell, monads, loops

I am working with a particular database where, upon a successful
query, you are able to access a group of chunks of the resulting data using a
specific command:

```
getResultData :: IO (ResponseCode, ByteString)
```

Now getResultData will return a response code and some data where
the response codes look like this:

```
response = GET_DATA_FAILED | OPERATION_SUCCEEDED | NO_MORE_DATA
```

The ByteString is one, some, or all of the chunks:

[image: Data]

The story does not end here. There exists a stream of groups:

[image: Stream]

Once receiving a NO_MORE_DATA response from getResultData, a call to
getNextItem will iterate the stream allowing me to start calls to
getResultData again. Once getNextItem returns STREAM_FINISHED, that's
all she wrote; I have my data.

Now, I wish to remodel this phenomenon with either Date.Iteratee or Data.Enumerator. Inasmuch as my
existing Data.Iteratee solution works, it yet seems very naive and I feel as if I should be modeling this
with nested iteratees as opposed to one big iteratee blob which is how
my solution is currently implemented.

I have been looking at the code of Data.Iteratee 0.8.6.2 and I am a bit confused
when it comes to the nested stuff.

**Are nested iteratees the proper course of action? If so, how would one model this with nested iteratees?**

Regards

Comment: I've never actually used Data.Iteratee or Data.Enumerator, but I feel the following questions are relevant nonetheless: Are chunks a fixed size? And, do you ever get partial chunks with `getResultData`, or do they always come through as whole chunks? The same questions apply to "groups".

Comment: Groups are of fixed size, but the command that reads the chunks from the groups may not always get the whole of the group in one call. The outer box is a group the inner boxes are chunks which, again, may or may not be read in a single call to getResultData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nested iteratees are the correct approach, but this case has some unique problems which make it slightly different from most common examples.

**Chunks and groups**

The first problem is to get the data source right.  Basically the logical divisions you've described would give you a stream equivalent to `[[ByteString]]`.  If you create an enumerator to produce this directly, each element within the stream would be a full group of chunks, which presumably you wish to avoid (for memory reasons).  You could flatten everything into a single `[ByteString]`, but then you'd need to re-introduce boundaries, which would be pretty wasteful since the db is doing it for you.

Ignoring the stream of groups for now, it appears that you need to divide the data into chunks yourself.  I would model this as:

```
enumGroup :: Enumerator ByteString IO a
enumGroup = enumFromCallback cb ()
 where
  cb () = do
    (code, data) <- getResultData
    case code of
        OPERATION_SUCCEEDED -> return $ Right ((True, ()), data)
        NO_MORE_DATA        -> return $ Right ((False, ()), data)
        GET_DATA_FAILED     -> return $ Left MyException
```

Since chunks are of a fixed size, you can easily chunk this with `Data.Iteratee.group`.

```
enumGroupChunked :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a -> IO (Iteratee ByteString IO a)
enumGroupChunked = enumGroup . joinI . group groupSize
```

Compare the type of this to `Enumerator`

```
type Enumerator s m a = Iteratee s m a -> m (Iteratee s m a)
```

So `enumGroupChunked` is basically a fancy enumerator which changes the stream type.  This means that it takes a [ByteString] iteratee consumer, and returns an iteratee which consumes plain bytestrings.  Often the return type of an enumerator doesn't matter; it's simply an iteratee which you evaluate with `run` (or `tryRun`) to get at the output, so you could do the same here:

```
evalGroupChunked :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a -> IO a
evalGroupChunked i = enumGroupChunked i >>= run
```

If you have more complicated processing to do on each group, the easiest place to do so would be in the `enumGroupChunked` function.

**Stream of groups**

Now this is out of the way, what to do about the stream of groups?  The answer depends on how you want to consume them.  If you want to essentially treat each group in the stream independently, I would do something similar to this:

```
foldStream :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a -> (b -> a -> b) -> b -> IO b
foldStream iter f acc0 = do
  val <- evalGroupChunked iter
  res <- getNextItem
  case res of 
        OPERATION_SUCCEEDED -> foldStream iter f $! f acc0 val
        NO_MORE_DATA        -> return $ f acc0 val
        GET_DATA_FAILED     -> error "had a problem"
```

However, let's say you want to do some sort of stream processing of the entire dataset, not just individual groups.  That is, you have a

```
bigProc :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a
```

that you want to run over the entire dataset.  This is where the return iteratee of an enumerator is useful.  Some earlier code will be slightly different now:

```
enumGroupChunked' :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a
  -> IO (Iteratee ByteString IO (Iteratee [ByteString] IO a))
enumGroupChunked' = enumGroup . group groupSize

procStream :: Iteratee [ByteString] IO a -> a
procStream iter = do
  i' <- enumGroupChunked' iter >>= run
  res <- getNextItem
  case res of 
        OPERATION_SUCCEEDED -> procStream i'
        NO_MORE_DATA        -> run i'
        GET_DATA_FAILED     -> error "had a problem"
```

This usage of nested iteratees (i.e. `Iteratee s1 m (Iteratee s2 m a)`) is slightly uncommon, but it's particularly helpful when you want to sequentially process data from multiple Enumerators.  The key is to recognize that `run`ing the outer iteratee will give you an iteratee which is ready to receive more data.  It's a model that works well in this case, because you can enumerate each group independently but process them as a single stream.

One caution: the inner iteratee will be in whatever state it was left in.  Suppose that the last chunk of a group may be smaller than a full chunk, e.g.

```
   Group A               Group B               Group C
   1024, 1024, 512       1024, 1024, 1024      1024, 1024, 1024
```

What will happen in this case is that, because `group` is combining data into chunks of size 1024, it will combine the last chunk of Group A with the first 512 bytes of Group B.  This isn't a problem with the `foldStream` example because that code terminates the inner iteratee (with `joinI`).  That means the groups are truly independent, so you have to treat them as such.  If you want to combine the groups as in `procStream`, you have to think of the entire stream.  If this is your case, then you'll need to use something more sophisticated than just `group`.

**Data.Iteratee vs Data.Enumerator**

Without getting into a debate of the merits of either package, not to mention [IterIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iterIO) (I'm admittedly biased), I would like to point out what I consider the most significant difference between the two: the abstraction of the stream.

In Data.Iteratee, a consumer `Iteratee ByteString m a` operates on a notional ByteString of some length, with access to a single chunk of `ByteString` at one time.

In Data.Enumerator, a consumer `Iteratee ByteString m a` operates on a notional [ByteString], with access to one or more elements (bytestrings) at one time.

This means that most Data.Iteratee operations are element-focused, that is with an `Iteratee ByteString` they'll operate on a single `Word8`, whereas Data.Enumerator operations are chunk-focused, operating on a `ByteString`.

You can think of `Data.Iteratee.Iteratee [s] m a` === `Data.Enumerator.Iteratee s m a`.